# Flutter - flutter_html package - customTextStyle isn't defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

As per the example in the flutter_html package, I am trying to add customTextStyle(the current size of the fonts is too small).
Each time I add the code from the example I get a red squiggly line (using Android Studio) telling me that it is not defined. Yet it is in the example:

```
  customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
    if (node is dom.Element) {
      switch (node.localName) {
        case "p":
          return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 20));
      }
    }
    return baseStyle;
  },
```

There is a mention in the example code (a comment) stating that:
`//Must have useRichText set to false for this to work.`

This is fine, but how do I set it to false? I tried to add this to various places in that very same code but it won't work and it will tell me that it is not defined. Do I need some additional package? This is not clear.

Thank you for your kind help with this.

This is a single_news_screen.dart file where I use this package. Code for this file is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:thw_network/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:thw_network/screens/main_screen.dart';

class SingleNewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  SingleNewsScreen({ this.dataNews });

  final dataNews;

  @override
  _SingleNewsScreenState createState() => _SingleNewsScreenState();
}

class _SingleNewsScreenState extends State<SingleNewsScreen> {

  dynamic news;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    news = widget.dataNews;
  }

  cardTitle(String title) {
    if(title.length > 120) {
      return title.substring(0,120) + '...';
    }
    return title;
  }
  cardDate(String date) {
    int year = int.parse(date.substring(0,4));
    int month = int.parse(date.substring(5,7));
    int day = int.parse(date.substring(8,10));
    return formatDate(DateTime(year, month, day), [d, ' ', M,', ', yyyy]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double contentHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 338;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFf5f5f5),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 260.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      news['jetpack_featured_media_url'],
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                        BlendMode.darken
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xFF1F1F98),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black],
                      stops: [0.0, 0.5]
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right:20, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                                  child: Text(
                                      'THE HIGHWIRE',
                                      style: kSingleOverlayAuthorTextStyle
                                  )
                              ), /* add child content here */
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right:20, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                                child: Text(
                                    cardTitle(news['title']['rendered']),
                                    style: kSingleOverlayTitleTextStyle
                                )
                              ), /* add child content here */
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right:20, bottom: 20, left: 20),
                                child: Text(
                                    cardDate(news['date']),
                                    style: kSingleOverlayDateTextStyle
                                )
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                          child: Align(

                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                elevation: 0,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                    return MainScreen();
                                  }),);
                                },
                                child: Icon(
                                    Icons.close,
                                    size: 25.0,
                                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: contentHeight,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Html(
                    data: news['content']['rendered'],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    onLinkTap: (url) async {
                      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                        await launch(url);
                      } else {
                        throw 'Could not launch $url';
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import this on the top of the widget

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;  // that is

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

For more details [flutter-html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#onlinktap)

Answer (score 0):

According to the authors, [its a bug (see the end of the README)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html).

> This package has a known issue where text does not wrap correctly.

I believe you need to set `useRichText: true` in the `Html()` widget. Probably right after  the `data:""` attribute

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is a bug, but I need that feature that comes with it. I have added `useRichText: true` straight after the data as you have suggested, however, I get an error that it is not defined. I am wondering if there is an default for font size for whole app that I might be able to change that would give me larger font size without needing to play around with it like I do now.

Comment: have you imported the package? may be you should update this question with the full source for us to get more context of this file

Comment: you are right. I have updated the question with code where I am using this package. Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no I haven't figured it out. I found some code to set up the default theme font size to a certain size, but it did not have any effect on the HTML code.

Comment: I am getting exact same error when I use useRichText: true, after data in html. Did you solve?